# How to use the same counter in two different classes

Tags: java, android, class, variables, android-fragments

I am creating a login fragment where the user can maximum try 3 times to login.

TO do so I wanted to use a counter in the `fragment`, but given that this fragment also contains an `asynctask class` for connecting to internet, it also needs to use the counter variable.

I know I could work with `SharedPreferences` but i was wondering if there was any better approach on it.

The code would be as follows:

```
public class loginfragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //CONNECT TO INTERNET!!
                task=new PasswordCheckTask();
                task.execute();
                //END CONNECT TO INTERNET!!
            }
        });
   }

   class PasswordCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            if (success == "1"){
                 Intent xx = new Intent(getContext().getApplicationContext(), ArduinoFirst.class);
                 xx.putExtra("position", position);
                 startActivity(xx);
                 counter=3; //Counter goes back to 3
            } else if (counter!=0) {
                 counter=counter-1 //One less try
            }
       }
 }
```

How would you do it?

Comment: since the PasswordCheckTask is a sub class of your fragment you can just declare the counter variable in the Fragment class scope and use it in the subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `PasswordCheckTask` class is a subclass of `loginfragment` (btw, the convention is to name it `LoginFragment`). So you could technically define a variable `counter` of `LoginFragment` and it can be accessed by both.

However, note that you're dealing with threads here, so you should use something like `AtomicInteger` or wrap calls to it using the `synchronized` keyword.

Example:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //CONNECT TO INTERNET!!
                task=new PasswordCheckTask();
                task.execute();
                //END CONNECT TO INTERNET!!
            }
        });
   }

   class PasswordCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            if (success == "1"){
                 Intent xx = new Intent(getContext().getApplicationContext(), ArduinoFirst.class);
                 xx.putExtra("position", position);
                 startActivity(xx);
                 counter.set(3);
            } else if (counter.get() != 0) {
                 counter.getAndDecrement();
            }
       }
 }
```

However, I've only seen you use the counter in the subclass `PasswordCheckTask` so you could have just defined it inside it, unless I've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of static variables it works fine any where

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Utils` class, and inside it define a `public static int` variable that you can reach from everywhere in your code.

Comment: Please don't do this. What you would be doing effectively is you create a global variable. This never is a good idee, sooner or later this gets you into trouble when you want to text or extend your code. Moreover with a static var you would only have one counter for all users.
As Guri Bambhrah said: you might just one to create a class that contains the counter. An instance of this class can be passed to everywhere you need the counter for the user. Or you might put the counter in the class representing the user anyway.